# How to fix flow type alias is not defined.eslint(no-undef) throwed by eslint

Tags: node.js, eslint, flowtype

I have file of types:

```
// @flow
export type RouteT = {
    api: string,
    method: string,
    route: string
}
```

And estlint throwing error `'RouteT' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)`.

What is wrong?

My `eslint` config is:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:flowtype/recommended" 
    ],
    "plugins": [ 
        "prefer-arrow",
        "flowtype"
    ],
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "classes": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "flowtype/define-flow-type": 0,
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single",
            {
                "allowTemplateLiterals": true
            }
        ],
        "eol-last": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": 1,
        "comma-dangle": [
            "error",
            "always-multiline"
        ],
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab",
            {
                "SwitchCase": 1
            }
        ],
        "no-else-return": "error",
        "no-tabs": 0,
        "no-var": "error",
        "radix": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "error",
        "brace-style": [
            "error",
            "1tbs"
        ],
        "no-multi-spaces": [
            "error"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ],
        "space-before-function-paren": [
            "error",
            {
                "anonymous": "always",
                "named": "always",
                "asyncArrow": "always"
            }
        ],
        "no-console": 0
    },
    "globals": {
        "logMsg": true
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Other types like `string`, `number` works correctly.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the full error including line number?

Comment: @LyleUnderwood 'RouteT' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)., 2nd line.